# Error with sed replacing string

Tags: bash, sed, grep, scripting

Hello I need to replace a string but i receive error using string 'return false;'

```
#!bin/bash
oldstring='{alert("bash")}'
newstring='{return false;}'
grep -rl $oldstring /home/commons.bundle.js | xargs sed -i s/$oldstring/$newstring/g
```

error:
sh deleteBoo.sh
sed: espressione -e #1, carattere 25: comando `s' non terminato

Comment: Quote your variable expansions - see [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/65304)

Comment: As two side notes, there's no need to recursively grep against one file; additionally, there's no need to grep for the string, since sed will only replace strings that it matched.

Comment: Running your script with `bash -x yourscript` might help in some cases. Paste it at http://shellcheck.net to check for errors with automatic suggestions how to fix some problems. (Unfortunately shellcheck doesn't suggest to quote all variables.)

Comment: Apart from what others have said, running `sed` from `xargs` with the output of `grep` will likely not do what you want as the lines matching the expression given to `grep` would be used as _arguments_, not input data, with `sed`.

Comment: @guest_7 Ah, yes. I did not see the `-l`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -rlZF -- "$oldstring" /home/commons.bundle.js |
xargs -r0 sed -i "s/$oldstring/$newstring/g" --
```

The following minor changes should make it work:

- grep should use `-F` so that the strings passed are not evaluated by grep as regexes.
- Another grep option to use is `-Z` which will pass filenames onto xargs using the null delimiter.
- At the receiving end, xargs with `-0` will unpack safely the filenames now. Nulls cannot occur in filenames by `law'